# Chrome in Linux Ubuntu stays in Full screen mode

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, google-chrome

I've recently installed the latest version of Chrome for Linux on my Ubuntu 9.10 installation. The only problem is is that it stays in Full Screen mode no matter what I do. I pressed F11 but it does not want to return to normal mode. I even completely uninstalled it using synaptic package manager en re-downloaded it and still nothing. Any suggestions will be welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You might try to remove your chrome config dir:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome
```

Deleting chrome via synaptic would not have deleted it.

- NOTE: this will uninstall all of your extensions and remove their data. There is another answer that talks about replacing the "bottom","left" etc.. Use that if you need to retain your extension data.

Answer (score 4):

load the file "~/.config/google-chrome/LocalState" into a text editor and change the values under "window_placement" so that the window will be smaller than your screen size, e.g I chose "bottom":500, "left":10, "right":1000, top:"50".

Answer (score 2):

Few other ways to solve this problem other than deleting the ~/.config/google-chrome dir completely.

I faced the same problem on  Centos 6.3 with Chrome version 24.0

The solution that I found :
**1. The easiest way:**

Exit chrome. Either by killing the command  (from top command or using kill -9 ) or switch to some other tasks (using alt-tab), and then right click on the chrome tab and close.

And the delete the Preference file from Defaults dir

```
 # rm -f ~/.config/google-chrome/Defaults/Preferences
```

(or move the file to some other dir `# mv ~/.config/google-chrome/Defaults/Preferences /var/tmp`)
  And start the chrome again. If you try this way, you will loose  some setting like  your login to google etc. But you won't loose your history or plugins..

**2. The other solution:**

Exit chrome.
   Edit the  ~/.config/google-chrome/Defaults/Preferences file. Seach for "window_placement", change the value of "right" which you can find inside the  "window_placement" section. You can find the current value to be the pixel size of your screen. Reduce the value by 100 pixel. (eg: if the value was 1280, change that to 1180)
   Save the file, and start chrome again..  You are not in full screen mode any more and you won't loose any thing  if you try this option.

Comment: Whatever I mentioned earlier is sort of work around. The real solution is posted here in this forum - http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=92495#c50   Look for the 50th comment there. You just need to change the short cut key in your system preference. I think this the right solution

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem on a dev build. Try scrolling to the top of the page and then putting your mouse pointer at the top of the screen and THEN hit F11. It may work it may not.

Comment: @Joel, thx for the answer, tried that, did not do the trick, Bozhidar's solution worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I have been having this issue with Chromium on ubuntu pangolin, and this gets fixed by running:

```
rm -rf ~/.config/chromium
```